# how to get the last userID from a database into textbox in asp.net

Tags: sql-server

Thanks I used the MAX statement and it doesn't return an error but still don't understand why it isn't working. My code is shown below:

```
Protected Sub txtuserID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtuserID.TextChanged
    Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\LostPropertyProject\App_Data\LostPropertyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    'Establish SQL Connection
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    'Open database connection to connect to SQL Server
    con.Open()
    'Data table is used to bind the resultant data
    Dim dtusers As New DataTable()
    'Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM tblUser"
    comm.Connection = con

    Dim MaxUserID As Object = comm.ExecuteScalar()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Also, I want the userID to be displayed in the textbox as soon as the page loads. How do I go about doing that? and thank you to everyone who replied to my question :) much appreciated

Comment: How do you define "last"? The last one created? Do you have a "date created" field?

Comment: Is this going to be used as the ID for a New User? If so, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(UserId) FROM User
```

This will give you the latest user id from the table.